# C language Libraries are precompiled. Then how is it linked in a different processor based computer?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, shared-libraries

Libraries are pre-compiled, whether they are static or dynamic. Thus if I compile a library in my computer (say an intel processor), how is my library going to help or "understood" when it is linked to source files in a different processor based computer? Libraries are at the end of the day object files. So how is a it gonna work for a different processor?

Comment: they will not work, you need to use different versions of the same library for different architectures

Comment: You always need to compile your code again if it is transferred to another architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not work. You have to compile a new version for the second processor using a compiler specific to that processor.

Comment: WoW64 is an emulation layer that translates 32bit instructions to 64bit instructions on the fly

Comment: and to create an universial binary you still need a compiler for every platform you want to support - the resulting binaries are just packaged to one file

Comment: yeah I know, still, you get a binary in an arch running in another in the end.

Comment: the same, a binary _compiled_ in an arch (sometimes ignorant it's being compiled for multiple) running in another different from the original it was compiled.